# draw uiimage along CGMutablePathRef

Tags: uiimage, drawing, quartz-core

How do i draw a custom uiimage along a CGMutablePathRef ? I can get the points from CGMutablePathRef but it does not give the smooth points that create the path.

I want to know if i can extract all of them plus the one that creat the smooth path.

i've used CGPathApply but i only get the control points, and when i draw my image it does not stay smooth as the original CGMutablePathRef

```
void pathFunction(void *info, const CGPathElement *element){
if (element->type == kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint)
{
    CGPoint firstPoint = element->points[1];
    CGPoint lastPoint = element->points[0];

    UIImage *tex = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
    CGPoint vector = CGPointMake(lastPoint.x - firstPoint.x, lastPoint.y - firstPoint.y);
    CGFloat distance = hypotf(vector.x, vector.y);
    vector.x /= distance;
    vector.y /= distance;
    for (CGFloat i = 0; i < distance; i += 1.0f) {
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake(firstPoint.x + i * vector.x, firstPoint.y + i * vector.y);
        [tex drawAtPoint:p blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for the function that is used to draw a cubic Bézier curve from a start point and an end point and two control points.

```
start⋅(1-t)^3 + 3⋅c1⋅t(1-t)^2 + 3⋅c2⋅t^2(1-t) + end⋅t^3
```

By setting a value for t between 0 and 1 you will get a point on the curve at a certain percentage of the curve length. I have a short description of how it works in the end of [this blog post](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/).

### Update

To find the point to draw the image somewhere between the start and end points you pick a t (for example 0.36 and use it to calculate the x and y value of that points.

```
CGPoint start, end, c1, c2; // set to some value of course
CGFloat t = 0.36;
CGFloat x = start.x*pow((1-t),3) + 3*c1.x*t*pow((1-t),2) + 3*c2.x*pow(t,2)*(1-t) + end.x*pow(t,3);
CGFloat y = start.y*pow((1-t),3) + 3*c1.y*t*pow((1-t),2) + 3*c2.y*pow(t,2)*(1-t) + end.y*pow(t,3);

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x,y); // this is 36% along the line of the curve
```

Which given the path in the image would correspond to the orange circle

[image: example]

If you do this for many points along the curve you will have many images positioned along the curve.

### Update 2

You are missing that `kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint` (implicitly) has 3 points: start (the current/previous points, the control point (`points[0]`) and the end point (`points[1]`). For a quad curve both control points are the same so `c1 = c2;`. For `kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint` you would get 2 different control points.

[image]

Comment: how do i apply it in my example?

Comment: i'm not getting there, as you can see in my example i have two points lastPoint and firstPoint and i want to draw an image between them to make the equivalent of a uibezier path, with my example it works but draws a straigth line and i wan a curve line as in uibezier... i don't know how to adapt your code to my example, because i don't know what values to put in c1 and c2.. the value for t i suppose it can be from 0 to 'distance' value. right?

Comment: For quads `points[0]` is both `c1` and `c2`. And no `t` really goes from 0 to 1, think of it as a percentage.